# Pixelated image downscaling in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I recently made a logo for my website with a resolution of 400x400. It scales down to 40x40 just fine in any other browser I have tested, but it acts weirdly in Edge. Every time I refresh the page, it renders properly for a split second, before changing to an ugly, pixelated look after the page completes loading.

How it looks before the page loads fully (and how I want it to look):

[image: How it looks before the page loads fully]

How it looks when page finishes loading:

[image: How it looks when page finishes loading]

HTML:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" class="logo">
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

EDIT: Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypqLb2jj/) to reproduce my problem.

Comment: Your top image appears to load fine for me in Edge, and your CSS also doesn't appear to affect anything. Is the image perfectly square by default? Do you have a link to the actual image causing a problem? Could you please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, I updated the post with a JSfiddle

Comment: ^ Thanks, that certainly shows the problem! What's interesting is that at full size, the image is blurry in both Chrome and Edge, though it's only blurry at 40px in Edge. I'd assume there's anti-aliasing going on.

Answer (score 16):

Poor-quality downscaling of images is a known problem in Edge, and has been for years now.

I can confirm your experience of seeing a brief flash of smoothly-rescaled image, too. And sometimes, just sometimes, an image seems to remain smoothly scaled! (It seems that one way to definitely re-create the problem is to re-size an image *after* the page is loaded, such as setting the size in your JSfiddle to 50x50px -- in Edge, the image resizes and looks awful, but in other browsers the result is smooth.)

The issue actually pre-dates the release of Edge. Recently MS seem to have fiddled with it, but they've certainly not fixed it. Here's a thread on an MS forum about it (note how some people are bizarrely desperate to wish the problem away, blaming it on graphics cards!): https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e800cbaf-a539-43ba-b5f9-1d29fe709ddc/the-awful-internet-explorer-image-renderengine

Here's another post from August 2015 about this issue, so it's definitely nothing new! https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9279264-better-image-scaling-no-more-jaggies-for-downscal

Really digging into the history, here's another demo -- from 2013! https://bug486918.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=428179

(That demo is from a comment on a MS blogpost from 2013: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2013/09/12/using-hardware-to-decode-and-load-jpg-images-up-to-45-faster-in-internet-explorer-11/ so it's been talked about for at least four years now!)

This same issue has been reported and confirmed as a bug by the Edge team twice, since at least November 2016, with no fix...

1 - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9869140/

2 - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14420925/

And there are several other posts about it here on SO.

The one possible solution seems to be rather OTT, adding the image to a canvas and rescaling that, but if you've got more than one or two images, this can cause serious lag: https://github.com/sukhoi1/ie-bicubic-img-interpolation-plugin/wiki

The only real solution seems to be to wait until MS fix this. Taking bets now on which year that will be!

Comment: Update - it's 2020 and this is still an issue.

Comment: its is june 17th 2020 and i'm stilling having clients asking me why their images look blury.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of improvement with my PNGs when I converted them to use the RGB color mode (used GIMP). It previously used 'indexed' colors.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this,
Edge down-scales the image when the size is large,

if we resize the image based on the actual size required the pixelation will be gone/reduced