# Animated GIFs are antialiased in Chrome but not Firefox or Edge

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, animated-gif, antialiasing

I have some icons that are set to animate on hover (so there are two images per icon, a static PNG and an animated GIF). Since the icons are meant to be responsive, I'm using Bootstrap's `img-fluid` class on each `img` element.

In Chrome, both the static image and the animated version display properly - edges are smooth and antialiased. In Firefox and Chrome, however, the animated GIFs appear pixelated and I have no idea why. Is this simply due to how each browser renders resized images, or is there a way I can fix it?

[Codepen sample here](https://codepen.io/aries0475/pen/EMPMMo) - hover over each icon to see what happens. In Firefox and Edge, there's a noticeable jump between the smooth-edged static PNG and the pixelated GIF. This doesn't happen in Chrome.

If it matters, my versions of each browser are:

- Firefox 65.0.1
- Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0
- Google Chrome
  72.0.3626.119

Help much appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a known issue, you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443161/pixelated-image-downscaling-in-microsoft-edge), you could also feedback your problem to [Edge Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443161/pixelated-image-downscaling-in-microsoft-edge).

Comment: Thanks for the info re Edge, though I'm still wondering why I'm seeing the same issue in Firefox. Another thing I'm noticing is that the pixellation is worse on some displays vs others. So...maybe this is something beyond my control :/